# BC30002 Type "SD2019.ProgressiveDBDataSet" is not defined

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2017 I have a database that I pulled in from Access and when I try to run the program and  I get **BC30002 Errors**.

I have tried to rebuild the program over and over but still get this error:

```
 BC30002  Type "SD2019.ProgressiveDBDataSet" is not defined. Type
 "SD2019.ProgressiveDBDataSetTableAdapters.ProgressiveDBTableAdapter"
 is not defined. Type
 "SD2019.ProgressiveDBDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager" is not
 defined.
```

What am I doing or not doing to get this database working?

Comment: how do you define these objects ?
please add this part of  code

Comment: Sorry but still learning at the same time building. I no im doing something wrong but what...